# Website Will not count unique surfers

Tags: php

I created a traffic exchange, and it gives me this error: Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double.object given in /home/rainingt/public_html/quadhits/index.php on line 165. How to fix this?

```
<tr>                            
    <td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: 
         <?= number_format( $C->sfrfv( 'sum(num)', '7statsite', 'where date="' . date( 'Y-m-d' ) . '"' ), 0, '', ' ' ) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: black">Pages yesterday</td>
    <td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: 
        <?= number_format( $C->sfrfv( 'sum(num)', '7statsite', 'where date="' . date( 'Y-m-d', time() - 86400 ) . '"' ), 0, '', ' ' ) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: black">Unique surfers today</td>
    (LINE 165)
    <td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: 
        <?= number_format( $C->sfrfv( 'count(usrid)', '7stat', 'where date="' . date( 'Y-m-d' ) . '" group by date' ), 0, '', ' ' ) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: black">Unique surfers yesterday</td>
    <td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">:
        <?= number_format( $C->sfrfv( 'count(usrid)', '7stat', 'where date="' . date( 'Y-m-d', time() - 86400 ) . '" group by date' ), 0, '', ' ' ) ?> 
</tr>
```

Comment: $C->sfrfv() is not returning a number !

Comment: please see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php it does not accept 3 parameters

Comment: Remember, SO is not a debug tool.

Comment: That's because your query object returns a result object, not the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `$C->sfrfv()` returns an object and not a double.

It's hard to say how to fix this without knowing the insides of the `sfrfv` method.

You should go into the `srfrv` method and make sure it returns a double / float / integer.